# Css loads very slow

Tags: php, functions, css

I have already searched about the problem but I didn't find something i understand, specifically for WordPress. Should I edit function.php of my theme somehow?

When the site loads the ugly sitemap appears and after a moment the site appears correctly.

I already fixed (only) the CSS errors seen in console and minified a big basic .css file

If you need the URL please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, because you said that at first moment site is ugly and soon after that site looks fine that problem is in position of css in your HTML code. For example if you load external .css file in your footer it will load after everything above, so you will see your site "as ugly" because that part of your code is loaded before, and your browser do not now how to style your site, until it load css.

If that is the case, put your css in header of html. Also, if you provide site link I can see more.

Comment: the site is anorado . gr 
as you said i already know that css loads last, but where can this be changed. i hope you can see in the site

Comment: As I can see is html source (of home page), ctr+F for ".css" site hase 24 external css files. I do not know which one is problem. But for me site design loads fine, I do not have "ugly" site. In your question you said "ugly sitemap appears...". Is problem with some specific for example sitemap at http://www.anorado.gr/sitemap.xml or with whole site?

Comment: Your sitemap.xml URL has no style file.

Comment: no i have problem with the hole site, when it loads the style loads slowly. Maybe sitemap weren't the better way to put it.

Comment: i mean the homepage for example. refreash it, can't you see the problem the first second?

Comment: Yes, at 1st second I see just some "dots". If you know you can put all of your 24 .css files in one file, or several, and link them in <head> of your HTML. Or, you can use plugins which can do that for you, for example try: [JS & CSS Script Optimizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/js-css-script-optimizer/) or [Better WordPress Minify](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-minify/) or [Merge + Minify + Refresh](https://wordpress.org/plugins/merge-minify-refresh/)